# mIRC Socket Chartset Fail

Tags: sockets, character-encoding, mirc

so i Have mIRC 7.21 that it has by default UTF-8 enabled.
So i have this socket:

```
on *:sockopen:_tmdb_*:{
  sockwrite -tn $sockname GET $hget($sockname,url) HTTP/1.1
  sockwrite -tn $sockname Host: "nah"
  sockwrite -tn $sockname User-Agent: mIRC-API/v1-Alpha
  sockwrite -tn $sockname Accept: application/json
  sockwrite -tn $sockname Connection: close
  sockwrite -tn $sockname $crlf $+ $crlf
}
```

I'm getting by default these headers by the remote server:

```
[Header] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[Header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[Header] Age: 0
[Header] Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
[Header] Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
.....
```

And i'm getting this response when it is written in english:

```
Extended Play 2006 47247
```

Though, when i'm trying to change the language. I'm making request to the api server
and defining &language=el. I'm getting this:

Headers:

```
[Header] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[Header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[Header] Age: 0
[Header] Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
[Header] Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
.....
```

Result:

```
Ξ Ξ­Ξ½Ο„Ξµ Ξ›ΞµΟ€Ο„Ξ¬ Ξ‘ΞΊΟΞΌΞ± 2006 47247
```

When i open the stored JSON file, mIRC downloaded... i can see just fine the greek
charset. mIRC Cannot.
Any ideas why my charset is getting messed up through sockets?
I mean i can just write fine with a small //echo -a Πεντε λεπτα ακόμη.
And it is displaying it just fine. Though through sockets is getting messed up..
[image: Extended Play]

Comment: mIRC can, But you will need to change your "Window" Font to Display and Decode UTF.

Answer (score 0):

```
if $utfdecode($utfencode($1-,162)) {
...
}
```

charset codes below, our charset code 162

```
000 - ANSI_CHARSET
001 - DEFAULT_CHARSET
002 - SYMBOL_CHARSET
077 - MAC_CHARSET
128 - SHIFTJIS_CHARSET
129 - HANGEUL_CHARSET
130 - JOHAB_CHARSET
134 - GB2312_CHARSET
136 - CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET
161 - GREEK_CHARSET
162 - TURKISH_CHARSET
163 - VIETNAMESE_CHARSET
177 - HEBREW_CHARSET
178 - ARABIC_CHARSET
186 - BALTIC_CHARSET
204 - RUSSIAN_CHARSET
222 - THAI_CHARSET
238 - EASTEUROPE_CHARSET
255 - OEM_CHARSET
```

Comment: and see bset binary identifer